# Laravel Mail Cannot Attach File

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-mail

The email will send but the file will not attach. Any ideas?

```
    public function email_invoice(Request $request, $id){

    $customer = customer::findOrFail($id);

    Mail::send('emails.invoice', ['customer' => $customer], function ($m) use ($customer) {
        $sender_name =  Auth::user()->name;
        $sender_email =  Auth::user()->email;
        $m->from( $sender_email, $sender_name);
        $m->to($customer->email)->subject('Invoice Attached');
        $m->attach('User/myName/invoice.pdf');
    });
}
```

Comment: The obvious question - are relative file paths allowed?  [All examples in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#attachments) show absolute paths.  Surely an absolute path, eg using [one of the path-related helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers), is a safer bet?

Comment: Don't Panic - that fixed it. It needed an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make **attach** function like this for email attachment

```
 $m->attach($file->getRealPath(), array(
                    'as' => $file->getClientOriginalName(), // If you want you can chnage original name to custom name      
                    'mime' => $file->getMimeType())
                );
```